# How to call a parent function within child in Native React

Tags: function, reactjs, react-native, parent-child, native

After hours spent googling around without finding an answer ... I'm asking for your help.

So what I want to do : Call the function named _toggleSearchBar() (which is in the parent) within the Child so when the onPress event (which is in the child) fire it changes the value 'isVisible' inside the parent.

**Parent**

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {isVisible: false};
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'P O S T E R',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#CECECE' },
    headerTitleStyle: { color: 'black', fontSize: 30, fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack'},
    headerRight: <DisplayIcon src={require('./ressources/icon_search.png')} myMethod={'HERE'}/>,
    headerLeft: <DisplayIcon src={require('./ressources/icon_aroundMe.png')}/>,
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
          <View style={styles.bck}>
          <ScrollView>
            <DisplayImage src={require('./ressources/logo.jpg')} />
            <DisplayImage src={require('./ressources/logo1.jpeg')} />
            <DisplayImage src={require('./ressources/logo2.jpg')} />
            <DisplayImage src={require('./ressources/logo3.jpeg')} />
            <DisplayImage src={require('./ressources/logo4.jpg')} />
            <DisplayImage src={require('./ressources/logo5.jpeg')} />
            <DisplayImage src={require('./ressources/bde.jpeg')} />
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
        <Display enable={this.state.isVisible} style={styles.ViewIn}>
          <View>
            <TextInput style={styles.textIn}></TextInput>
          </View>
        </Display>
      </View>
    )
  }
  _toggleSearchBar() {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      return { isVisible: !this.state.isVisible };
    });
  }
}
```

**Child**

```
class DisplayIcon extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.myMethod} activeOpacity= {0.4} underlayColor={ 'rgb(206, 206, 206)' }>
        <Image style={styles.Picture} source={this.props.src}/>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Picture: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
  }
});
```

Bind didn't work. Nor passing the function via props ...

Thanks for your help and your time !

Comment: Please do not post images of your code. Add your code directly into question for help people to help you.

Comment: Alright, my bad

Comment: Where is the DisplayIcon component located in the hierarchy? Because what I see in your HomeScreen is only DisplayImage. Are DisplayImage and DisplayIcon the same component?

Answer (score 0):

In the **Child** component you should invoke `this.props.myMethod` and not `this.myMethod`.
Example:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.myMethod} activeOpacity= {0.4} underlayColor={ 'rgb(206, 206, 206)' }>
```

In your **Parent** you should pass in a prop to the child - `myMethod={this._toggleSearchBar}`.
Example:

```
<DisplayIcon src={require('./ressources/icon_search.png')} myMethod={this._toggleSearchBar}/>
```

Note that you should bind `_toggleSearchBar` to the `class`.
Do it in the `constructor`:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this._toggleSearchBar = this._toggleSearchBar.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: No errors, but nothing shows up as it suppose to. I was guessing that my code was wrong so I change the function to alert('azert'); ... still no errors but I'm not passing in the function when I click as the alert doesn't shows up

Answer (score 0):

**HELP FOR COMPREHENSION**

Inside the child.

This is not working (via Parent function)

```html
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.myMethod} activeOpacity= {0.4} underlayColor={ 'rgb(206, 206, 206)' } style={styles.lol}>
        <Image style={styles.Picture} source={this.props.src}/>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

This is working (via child function)

```html
  lol() {
    alert('lol');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.lol} activeOpacity= {0.4} underlayColor={ 'rgb(206, 206, 206)' } style={styles.lol}>
        <Image style={styles.Picture} source={this.props.src}/>
      </TouchableHighlight>
```